# concurrently handle input does not work as expected

Tags: npm-scripts, concurrently

I am trying to combine two shell commands with `concurrently` lib and there should be option to forward user input into one of the child processes, see [docs here](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently), section `--handle-input`. But it somehow does not work in my case:
npm script

```json
    "test:unit": "concurrently --kill-others --handle-input --names test,build \"vitest --environment jsdom\" \"vite build --watch\"",
```

results in

```
[test]      Tests  1 failed | 12 passed (13)
[test]       Time  94ms
[test] 
[test] 
[test]  FAIL  Tests failed. Watching for file changes...
[test]        press u to update snapshot, press h to show help
```

I am pressing "u" as when I run it separately but nothing happen, even I tried to confirm by enter key.

So maybe I understand lib wrongly, or something. How can I pass my key strokes to child process "test"?

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: I have found https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently/issues/191#issuecomment-522210540 that it might be due to "raw stdin" which for now I don't understand yet as an frontend guy I didn’t meet that term yet.. I will try to google more to understand better

Answer (score 2):

I get help in mentioned [github issue](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently/issues/191#issuecomment-1224276270). CREDIT to [Mr. Pascal Jufer](https://github.com/paescuj)

Using `--raw` option did the thing!

So my final script is:

```json
"test:unit": "concurrently --raw --kill-others --handle-input --names test,build \"vitest --environment jsdom\" \"vite build --watch\"",
```